# Why the Binding variable is not synched with the TextField text in custom View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having trouble with `TextField` with the `@Binding` variable in the custom view component. I expect the `text` to be synched with the value user input and shown in the sheet. However, it shows empty, which means the `text` in ContentView is not updated. It's probably basic but why the below code does not work as expected?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var present = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Input(text: $text)

            Button("Submit") {
                present = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $present) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

struct Input: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("hint", text: $text)
    }
}
```

It's weird but it works if I add `Text` to ContentView as below. Why?

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ADDED
            Text(text)
                .font(.title)

            Input(text: $text)

            Button("Submit") {
                present = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $present) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
```

Also, I'm aware it works if I use custom Binding to pass to the `Input` view.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Custom Binding
            Input(text: .init(get: { text }, set: { text = $0 }))

            Button("Submit") {
                present = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $present) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even just adding `let x = text` in the `VStack` works. Not sure if this is intentional. SwiftUI doesn't seem to treat the VStack (and by extension the sheet) as a view that needs updating when `text` changes.

Comment: use `sheet(item:)` or `sheet(isPresented: $present) { [text] in ... }`

Comment: Wow, `sheet(isPresented: $present) { [text] in ... }` works. But why?

Comment: @Toru please close the question once it is answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ContentView`'s `body` you didn't call the `text` state getter anywhere (the sheet closure does not count) so SwiftUI's dependency tracking didn't think you care about changes.

You can force it to call `body` by calling the `text` state getter like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $present) { [text] in
```

This is called a capture list.

You could also put `let _ = text` at the top of body.

It's unusual to declare a state in a `View` and not use it in `body` so when this problem happens it's a sign the Views are not structured correctly, or just haven't been implemented fully yet.